# C# LINQ. Searching for object by object name property or name part

Tags: c#, linq, object, search

I am trying to find all invoices to buyers, searching by buyer name (contains and equals filter). Looking for the cleanest way to do it.
I have a list of Buyers.

```
List <Buyer> AllBuyers;
```

And a Buyer is:

```
public class Buyer
    {
        public string BuyerIdentifier{ get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

I have a list of Invoices to buyers.

```
List <Invoice> AllInvoices;
```

And an Invoice is

```
public class Invoice
    {
        public string InvoiceID { get; set; }
        public string BuyerID { get; set; }
        public string Amount{ get; set; }
    }
```

What I am doing currently:

```
List<string> BuyerIDs = new List<string> { };
foreach (Invoice inv in AllInvoices)
{
    if (!(BuyerIDs.Contains(inv.BuyerID)))
    {
         // add BuyerID to list if it's not already there. Getting id's that are present on invoices and whose Buyer names match using contains or equals
        BuyerIDs.Add(AllBuyers.First(b => b.BuyerIdentifier == inv.BuyerID
          && (b.Name.IndexOf(SearchValue, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)).BuyerIdentifier);
    }                                                
 }
 Invoices = AllInvoices.FindAll(i=> BuyerIDs.Contains(i.BuyerID));
```

LINQ query syntax is a little easier for me to understand than LINQ methods to join. So after replies below I am now doing this:

```
Invoices  =  (from buyer in AllBuyers
              join invoice in AllInvoices on buyer.BuyerIdentifier equals invoice.BuyerID
              where buyer.Name.IndexOf(SearchValue, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0                                 
              select invoice).ToList();
```

Comment: Does your code work? If it does and you are just looking to improve your code, this question probably belongs on [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), and not here. Otherwise, what problem are you having, or what error are you seeing?

Comment: It works, I just wonder if there is a better way in LINQ to do it without  foreach loop and if condition.

Comment: I don't know what your doing, but you probably just be doing a join

Comment: What is pair.Value? Looks like there's something missing

Comment: Thanks, forgot to replace that one. It's the search value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you need are the invoices, you could join your two collections, filter, and select the invoices

```
AllBuyers.Join(AllInvoices, 
            a => a.BuyerIdentifier, 
            a => a.BuyerID, 
            (b, i) => new { Buyer = b, Invoice = i })
    .Where(a => a.Buyer.Name.Contains("name"))
    .Select(a => a.Invoice).ToList();
```

If you want the buyers as well, just leave out the `.Select(a => a.Invoice)`.
The `Contains` method of a string will match an equals as well.

Comment: Thanks, I guess join is what I was looking for. As for Contains, I wanted case insensitive search and didn't want to use toLower().

Comment: I think you would benefit from filtering buyers before performing the join. I guess that's what the OP intends after his last edit. That is, he intends to filter buyers by a search value on the name (which will potentially reduce the full list of buyers significantly)

Comment: Just one warning for the join, if you can not guarantee that you have every Buyer only once in the list, you would get duplicit Invoices in the result.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a suggestion where I create a dictionary with BuyerIdentifier as keys and a List of Invoices as values:

```
var dict = AllBuyers.ToDictionary(k => k.BuyerIdentifier,
                v => AllInvoices.Where(i => i.BuyerID == v.BuyerIdentifier).ToList());
```

Then you can access a list of Invoices for a specific buyer like so:

```
List<Invoice> buyerInvoices = dict[buyerId];
```

Comment: This is horribly inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
var InvoiceGrouping = AllInvoices.GroupBy(invoice => invoice.BuyerID)
                                 .Where(grouping => AllBuyers.Any(buyer => buyer.BuyerIdentifier == grouping.Key && buyer.Name.IndexOf(pair.Value, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0));
```

What you end up with is a grouping which has a buyer's ID as the key and all their invoices as the value.

If you want just a flat list of invoices, you can do like so:

```
var Invoices = AllInvoices.GroupBy(invoice => invoice.BuyerID)
                          .Where(grouping => AllBuyers.Any(buyer => buyer.BuyerIdentifier == grouping.Key && buyer.Name.IndexOf(pair.Value, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0))
                          .SelectMany(grouping => grouping);
```

Note the added `SelectMany` at the end which, since `IGrouping` implements `IEnumerable`, flattens the groupings into a single enumeration of values.

Answer (score 0):

As an `ILookup` fanboy, this would be my approach:

```
var buyerMap = AllBuyers
    .Where(b => b.Name.IndexOf(SearchValue, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
    .ToDictionary(b => b.BuyerIdentifier);

var invoiceLookup = AllInvoices
    .Where(i => buyerMap.ContainsKey(i.BuyerID))
    .ToLookup(x => x.BuyerID);

foreach (var invoiceGroup in invoiceLookup)
{
    var buyerId = invoiceGroup.Key;
    var buyer = buyerMap[buyerId];
    var invoicesForBuyer = invoiceGroup.ToList();

    // Do your stuff with buyer and invoicesForBuyer
}
```

Comment: Actually, you don't need lookup, `GroupBy` would be enough and probably cleaner